# How to clone a corrupted git repo

Tags: git

The error I get from trying to clone the repo:

```
$ git clone git@repo.xx.xx.com:project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: fatal: empty filename in tree entry
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Do you have administrative access to `repo.xx.xx.com`? Are there backups? Or other (clean) clones?

Comment: I have access to the repo, no backups or any clean clones.

Comment: I'd probably start with backing up what you have and then running `git gc` on the server.

Comment: I don't have anything (first time cloning this repo)

Comment: I think it may be corrupted recently, is there a way to clone the repo at a particular date?

Comment: I interpreted "I have access to the repo" as a yes response to "Do you have administrative access to `repo.xx.xx.com`?" So that's a no? The easiest way to clone an "earlier version" is if there's a tag or branch pointing to an older commit. Does either of those exist?

Comment: oh, no administrative access. I don't know what tags or branches this repo contains.

Comment: Try running `git ls-remote git@repo.xx.xx.com:project.git`. This should show you all available refs. See if one of those looks like a good candidate.

Comment: Also, can you contact whoever admins the server? They may have backups or otherwise be able to recover the repo.

Comment: @Chris cool I see a few refs, this is a dumb question, but how do I use those refs?

Comment: See if `git clone --single-branch --branch refname git@repo.xx.xx.com:project.git` gets you anywhere.

Comment: cool one of the branches worked! now to figure out why `master` branch doesn't...

Comment: Great! I've added an answer summarizing what we did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having administrative access to the server or a clean copy there's very little that you can do. However, since you believe the corruption affects some recent commit you can try cloning another branch and see if that works.

First, let's see what's available to clone:

```
git ls-remote git@repo.xx.xx.com:project.git
```

This should give you a list of refs available on the server. Once you find a candidate, try cloning it with

```
git clone --single-branch --branch refname git@repo.xx.xx.com:project.git
```